# One is outstanding, another doesn't belong : Says Grandpa

Tags: knowledge, word-property

"Here is a group of words with a specific property-- except for one", said Grandpa. He had his Merriam Webster dictionary out.

I looked at them.

> Raking
>
> Finest
>
> Latest
>
> Parent
>
> Flawed
>
> Piking
>
> Basest
>
> Really

"They are all six letter words and all start and end with consonants", I observed.

"Brilliant, Einstein!" Grandpa interrupted.

> "Now one word in that group not only follows that property, but extends
>   it further. It stands out."
>
> "Also, I just checked in my dictionary. One of the words does not
>   belong to this group," said Grandpa.

"So what is that property, and what are those two words, son? Make sure your answer only involves MW or Collins dictionary words and no proper nouns or abbreviations are allowed."

I started scratching my head.

HINT

> Focus on 2 letters at a time

Comment: Just to clarify, are "except for one" at the start and "One of the words does not belong to this group" referring to the same thing, or are these two odd-ones-out of different kinds somehow?

Comment: Both are same statements @Gareth McCaughan. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The property is each word can be broken into its initial or latter two-thirds and be a valid 4 letter word. Raking extends this property as its middle two-thirds (not sure that's the best way to say that?) is also a valid 4 letter word. Basest is the exclusion, as it doesn't end in a valid 4 letter word.

Raking

> This is our word extending the rule as it can be broken into 3 four letter words as opposed to two. 'raki' is a Turkish liquor, then we have 'akin' in the middle 4, and 'king' at the end.

Finest

> for this we get 'fine' and 'nest'

Latest

> here we get 'late' and 'test'

Parent

> here we get 'pare' and 'rent'

Flawed

> and this is 'flaw' and 'awed'

Piking

> this is 'piki' (a traditional southwestern US native american bread) and 'king'

Basest

> This is our odd one out as it only has a 4 letter word to start, 'base'

Really

> lastly this is 'real' and 'ally'

Thanks @Prim3numbah and @GarethMcCaughan, I got a huge head start reading your answers. Also not sure mine is enough different to be right/what OP is looking for, but wanted to point out they all start with valid 4 letter words as well.

Comment: You've gone further than Prim3numbah and Gareth, but I've managed to take it *even further*. How deep does this rabbit hole go?

Answer (score 7):

I believe the property is..

> The last 4 letters of the words form another word. These are Fi**nest**, La**test**, Pa**rent**, Fl**awed**, Pi**king**, Re**ally**. The only word that *extends* this property is R**aking**(two words; *a* *king*). And the word that doesn't belong to this group of words is basest because **sest** is not a word in the MW or Collins dictionary.

Comment: Check again @Prim3numbah. Which word stands out and why? There is a lot more to this.

Comment: rot13(v whfg ernyvfrq 'n grfg' naq 'n erag' vf nyfb gjb jbeqf. Qvqa'g ernyyl guvax guvf bar guebhtu :Q

Ohg sebz jung v pna frr, gur jbeq 'ernyyl' qbrf abg raq jvgu n pbafbanag. Naq gur jbeq 'synjrq'vf gur bayl jbeq gung unf n pbafbanag nf n frpbaq yrggre.)

Comment: Lbh jrer xvaq bs ba gur evtug genpx. Xrrc ybbxvat sbe jbeqf vafvqr gurfr jbeqf

Answer (score 7):

Extending the answers previously given even further, and following the latest hint:

> each word can have **two adjacent letters removed from it** in **at least three different ways** (removing letters 1&2, 3&4, 5&6) and still give a valid word.

In fact,

> all except FLAWED and REALLY can have two adjacent letters removed in at least *four* different ways and still give a valid word. Even the exception BASEST still fits this condition. And the outstanding word is PARENT, which can have two adjacent letters removed in any of the maximum possible *five* ways and still give a valid word!

Raking:

> KING, RANG, RAKI, also RING, but not RAKG.

Finest:

> NEST, FIST, FINE, also FEST, but not FINT.

Latest:

> TEST, LAST, LATE, also LEST, but not LATT.

Parent:

> RENT, PENT, PANT, PART, PARE. This one is outstanding!

Flawed:

> AWED, FLED, FLAW, but not FWED or FLAD.

Piking:

> KING, PING, PIKI, also PING (again), but not PIKG.

Basest:

> BEST, BAST, BASE, also BAST (again), but not SEST. This one is the exception.

Really:

> ALLY, RELY, REAL, but not RLLY or REAY.

Comment: rot13(Guvf frrzf evtug. Rkprcg, yvxr lbh fnl, gung vg'f gjb jbeqf gung qb abg sbyybj gur cebcregl.

V guvax znlor gur jbeq gung qb abg orybat va guvf tebhc vf "Ernyyl". Sbe nabgure ernfba. Nppbeqvat gb gur zreevnz jrofgre qvpgvbanel(fvapr ur unq n ZJ qvpgvbanel jvgu uvz), l vf pbafvqrerq n ibjry vs vgf ng gur raq bs n jbeq. Naq vgf haqrefgbbq,  gung gur fgneg naq gur raq bs gur jbeqf *zhfg* or pbafbanagf. Pbhyq or bire-guvaxvat vg bsp, ohg jnagrq gb cbvag gung bhg.

Comment: @Prim3numbah That comment didn't even need to be rot13'ed ... nothing in there is giving away the answer.

Comment: @Rand al'Thor, you took it one step further. I was thinking of just removal of 2 consecutive letters and still have valid words. So Raking : King, Rang and Raki. Parent is the only one where the 2 letters can be removed consecutively as you pointed out: Rent, Pent, Pant, Part and Pare.

Comment: @DEEM I don't understand the distinction you're making? I'm also looking at the removal of 2 consecutive letters each time, in each of the different ways that can be done.

Comment: As in, pair letter 1&2, pair letter 3&4 and pair letter 5&6

Comment: @Prim3numbah Oh, I see. Then two of them have the property, five of them have it even more, and one of them has it even super more :-P

Comment: @DEEM Edited, is it right now?

Comment: It is OK now @R

Comment: Why was the other answer accepted if it wasn't completely correct?

Comment: Dunno ferret, ask @DEEM.

Comment: I don't really understand the criteria for not belonging. Is it the position?

Comment: @EgorHans Yes: the OP was interested in removing specific pairs of letters (1&2, 3&4, 5&6), not just any two adjacent letters as I originally thought.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure Prim3numbah has the basic property right:

> all but BASEST end with a valid 4-letter word.

Perhaps the one that stands out is

> RAKING

since

> AKIN (letters 2..5) is a word as well as KING (letters 3..6).

I have to confess that

> this seems less impressive to me than *two* of the other words, LATEST and PARENT, both of which have the property that if you divide the letters into pairs LA|TE|ST or  PA|RE|NT then *any two* of the pairs make a word: LATE, LAST, TEST; PARE, PANT, RENT. But there doesn't seem to be much to choose between these two, whereas RAKING is the only one with a 4-letter word in the middle. (Some dictionaries list ST as a word, in which case LATEST would win because LA and TE are both words too, being sol-fa note names; but M-W and Collins don't do that.)