# A six letter body part

Tags: word, no-computers

The question relates to a recent puzzle: [One is outstanding, another doesn't belong : Says Grandpa](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/94723)

Take the word PARENT for example.

> If you take 2 consecutive letters out, the remaining four letters give
>   you valid words:
>
> RENT  PENT  PANT  PART  PARE

Note you do not even have to anagram those 4 letters.

However, if you put another restriction:

> Take ANY TWO LETTERS out from that word, the remaining four letters give
>   you valid words

then it does not work. If you take A and E out, the remaining 4 letters do not form a word even if you allow anagrams.

It is very hard to find words with that restriction. So here is the question:

> Find **a six letter word which is a body part** such that, if you take ***any*** 2 letters out, the remaining 4 letters or their anagram form words that are in Merriam Webster dictionary. No abbreviations, proper nouns or acronyms.
>
> The anagram of the original word itself describes a type of material.

Another interesting thing about the same word: the same restriction described above also holds for taking any 1 letter out.

> Hint
>
> As many of you have thought of this already
>
> Are there 4 letter words with consonants only?

Enjoy.

Comment: Want to put a [tag:no-computers] tag on this? Otherwise someone is just going to brute-force a dictionary database to find it.

Comment: I was just about to start coding, @Randal'Thor, <sigh>

Comment: Is the word in medical terminology form or more commonly used?

Comment: Probably Medically Named. Not very common like hand or ear

Comment: @Rand al'Thor An ignorant question. How do you insert puzzle links in the question? Also how do you insert a web site link in the question?

Comment: @DEEM You can link to anything by using square and round brackets: `[text](http://link.com)` renders as [text](http://link.com). For linking to another post *on this site*, you can simply paste the URL and it will render nicely when you post the question (as I did in your question here).

Comment: Based on the rule that this also works with 1 letter, I take this to mean that rot13(Guvf jbeq cebonoyl pbagnvaf gjb yrggref F? V thrff vg'f rnfvre gb znxr jbeqf cyheny gung jnl.)?

And this would also mean that rot13(Gurer unf gb or n znkvzhz bs guerr pbafbanagf, fvapr lbh pna'g znxr n 4-yrggre jbeq whfg sebz pbafbanagf)?

Comment: Aha @VirtualValentin. You CAN do what you said in the last sentence.

Comment: Are only body-part answers acceptable? My LEASES/EASELS answer was just deleted for being "not an answer" to the question asked.

Comment: I am expecting the answer to meet all restrictions. One is already in and I have another. Please note that I did not delete your answer, I upvoted it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Credit to VirtualValentin for his comment inspiring me to find the answer.  The body part is:

> **STAPES**, a bone in the ear

4 letter anagrams:

> The key anagram is PSST which was inspired by VirtualValentin's comment and DEEM's response.  List of anagrams:
>
>  STAP = PAST
>  STAE = EATS
>  STAS = TASS (a Scottish drinking bowl)
>  STPE = PEST
>  STPS = PSST
>  STES = SETS
>  SAPE = PEAS
>  SAPS = SAPS
>  SAES = SEAS
>  SPES = SEPS (a type of lizard)
>  TAPE = TAPE
>  TAPS = TAPS
>  TAES = SEAT
>  TPES = PEST
>  APES = APES

5 letter anagrams:

> STAPE = TAPES
>  STAPS = PASTS
>  STAES = SEATS
>  STPES = PESTS
>  SAPES = APSES
>  TAPES = TAPES

The word itself is an anagram of:

> PASTES, a type of material

Answer (score 19):

> **RETINA**

4 Letters

> tina [anti](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anti)
> eina [-inae](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-inae)
> etna [neat](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/neat)
> etia [itea](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/itea)
> etin [tine](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tine)
> rina [rain](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rain)
> rtna [rant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rant)
> rtia [airt](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/airt)
> rtin [trin](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trin)
> rena [near](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/near)
> reia [arie](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arie)
> rein [rein](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rein)
> reta [rate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rate)
> retn [rent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rent)
> reti [tire](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tire)

5 Letters

> etina [tinea](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tinea)
> rtina [train](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/train)
> reina [Irena](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Irena)
> retna [antre](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antre)
> retia [irate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irate)
> retin [trine](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trine)

6 Letters

> retina [ratine](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ratine)

As to the no-computers tag, I came up with the solution and found all the definitions by hand - but I used a computer to format it all nicely. =)

Comment: [Erm.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/95030/a-six-letter-body-part/95034?noredirect=1#comment271820_95031) I didn't realise that the suffix "inae" would count :-) +1 to you good sir.

Comment: I do have an answer which is different

Comment: -inae is a bit weak, I suppose, as is Irena (a genus of birds, maybe considered a proper noun). But once I found an entry in MW for everything, I didn't think it particularly plausible there could be two such words!

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if it's what you had in mind, but I believe the word could be

> TISSUE (which is both a part of the body and a material)

---

Words (each have an entry on Merriam-Webster Dictionary although two are not technically English):

> SUES
>  UTES
>  ETUI
>  SITE
>  SITS
>  SUIT
>  EIUS (Latin)
>  SETS
>  SEIS
>  SUIS (French)

Comment: What do you get if you remove I and E?

Comment: @DanielMathias Looks like I may have missed that one. Maybe [tuss](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tuss) (from Middle English)?

Comment: Merriam Webster doesn't like that one.

Comment: @DanielMathias I noticed. OP probably has a better answer in mind, but this is almost an alternative answer.

Comment: Almost :-) RETINA and BOWELS are *almost* alternative answers. I've found a few with *lots* of possible 2-letter removals, but not yet one with all.

Comment: And there is that thing about 1 letter removal too!

Answer (score 1):

> WEINER

Removing two letters:

> WREN
>  REIN
>  WINE
>  WIRE
>  [ERNE](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/erne)
>  WERE

Comment: I am sorry but first of all I would not think of such a word. Secondly I could not find RINE in MW dictionary.https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rine

Comment: @DEEM REIN is there, though. And why wouldn't you think of such a word? It's not a body part, but it's a [valid word](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/weiner).

Comment: @Rewan It does provide an answer to the question?

Comment: One line was : Another interesting thing about the same word: the same restriction described above also holds for taking any 1 letter out. Can you find words if you remove W or N?

Comment: What three words can you form if you remove two consonants, leaving EEIN, EEIR, EEIW?

Comment: @aschepler [inee](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inee#English), [eire](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eire#Middle_English) and [weie](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/weie#Middle_English)